# Append form elements via jQuery doesn't work in firefox

Tags: jquery, forms, element

I'm using jQuery to create elements form and inputs.
It works fine in Chrome, but not in firefox.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.criarPost = function(url,campos) {

        var form;
        form = $("<form>").attr({ "action": url, "enctype": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "method": "POST", "id":"postlink"});
        campos = campos.split("&");
        $.map(campos, function (key,item) {
            campo = key.split("=");
            $("<input>").attr({ name: campo[0], value: decodeURIComponent(campo[1]) }).appendTo(form);
        });
        $(form).submit();

    };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: What about `$.fn.criarPost = function(url, campos) { $.post(url, campos, function() { alert('Post criado.'); }); };` ?

Comment: Try something more like this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yqhNM/1/)

Comment: I not want use jax, need post reload page

Comment: I solve, only replace $(form).submit() for $("body").append(form).submit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that Firefox will not submit a form that is not part of the DOM. You could try appending it to the document and then submitting it, like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.criarPost = function(url, queryString) {

        var form = $('<form id="postlink" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST" style="display: none;">').attr({ 'action': url });

        var params = queryString.split("&");

        $.each(params, function (i, param) {
            var nameValue = param.split('=');
            $("<input>").attr({ name: nameValue[0], value: decodeURIComponent(nameValue[1]) }).appendTo(form);
        });

        $(document.body).append(form);

        form.submit();
    };
})(jQuery);
```